# How to print floats from string in python?

Tags: python, precision

Here is an example:

```
x = ["changes": {"Average Response Time": ["22.93705940246582", "21.93705940246582"]}},]
```

How to extract only floats that I will recieve:

```
22.93705940246582

21.93705940246582
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, it should be `x = [{"changes": {"Average Response Time": ["22.93705940246582", "21.93705940246582"]}},]`.

Comment: Either you have a typo or `x` is not a valid python object.

Comment: You can't print floats...

Comment: *there are no floats in your dictionary*. This is crucial to understand. In any case, are you basically asking how to use a dict?

Comment: @JeffUK What do you mean? Of course you can print floats. E.g. `print(0.0)` -> `0.0`

Comment: @JeffUK well, one says that they print an object in Python, and that entails converting that object to some string representation to write to some buffer (i.e. standard out)\

Comment: Seems like you are just starting to learn Python. Best thing is to start with some tutorials, rather than asking questions here. For example, find a tutorial on lists and dictionaries which explains how to extract their values (known as 'indexing').

Comment: Are you trying to extract out the list i.e. after the syntax correction mentioned by funilrys you can use `x[0]['changes']["Average Response Time"]` to get ['22.93705940246582', '21.93705940246582']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong since you used `"changes":`  But write as a list, it should be a big dict outside. Your code should look like this:

You can do this:

```
x = {"changes": {"Average Response Time": ["22.93705940246582", "21.93705940246582"]}}
```

Then you can do:

```
print(x['changes']['Average Response Time'])
```

which gives you:

```
['22.93705940246582', '21.93705940246582']
```

If you want the first float:

```
print(x['changes']['Average Response Time'][0])
```

Otherwise, if you don't want a dict but want to make it a list. You can use this regular expression which will give you the numbers you want:

```
regex_digit_match = re.compile(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)")
regex_digit_match.findall(yourlist[index])
```

Answer (score 2):

It is somehow "possible" but I will recommend you to start learning about [Dictionnaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and Python data structure first.

Once you fixed your `SyntaxError`, assuming you have:

```
x = [{"changes": {"Average Response Time": ["22.93705940246582", "21.93705940246582"]}},]
```

You should be able to do:

```
print("\n\n".join(x[0]["changes"]["Average Response Time"]))
```

---

Full output:

```
>>> x = [{"changes": {"Average Response Time": ["22.93705940246582", "21.93705940246582"]}},]
>>> print("\n\n".join(x[0]["changes"]["Average Response Time"]))
22.93705940246582

21.93705940246582
>>>
```

---

About `\n`: It's the equivalent of "new line".

About `x[0]["changes"]["Average Response Time"]`: Your `x` variable is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of [dictionnaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).
To understand let's take it to step by step:

1. Here we can see that we got the first element of the list which is a dictionary.

```py
>>> x[0]
{'changes': {'Average Response Time': ['22.93705940246582', 
'21.93705940246582']}}
>>>
```

2. We are looking for the "floats" - which are actually strings by the way. Meaning that we first have to "select" the `"changes"` key. That's what we do here.

```py
x[0]["changes"]
{'Average Response Time': ['22.93705940246582', '21.93705940246582']}
>>>
```

3. We now have to "select" the `"Average Response Time"` key. Same as before.

```py
>>> x[0]["changes"]["Average Response Time"]
['22.93705940246582', '21.93705940246582']
>>>
```

About [**`str.join()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. A [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

---

I hope this helps, but please learn about Python lists, dictionaries, and data structure ASAP...